# grails IntegrationSpec : how to make it not rollback

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, integration-testing, spock

I want to below test code to not rollback after the test finishes.

I inserted the data on mysql but it is never committed.

I used **@Rollback** and many things with no success.

The test code is like below.

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
import grails.transaction.Rollback;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import spock.lang.*
import com.ms.domain.WordInSentence

class CompanyServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    CompanyService companyService;

    void "count login to private area"() {
        setup:''
        when:''
        then:''
//          def transaction = sessionFactory.currentSession.beginTransaction()
            companyService.scoreCompany();
//          transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

The service class.

```
@Transactional
class CompanyService {

    def dataSource;

    void scoreCompany() {
        WordInSentence wis = new WordInSentence()
        wis.word = "a"
        wis.location = 1;
        wis.sentence_id = 1
        wis.save(flush:true);
        wis.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Integration tests are `transactional` by default. You can set `static transactional = false` in the spec at class level to deviate from that behavior. But extra care has to be taken to clear data between tests if you do not want to pollute each test case.

Comment: @dmahapatro  : thanks a lot! this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting)

> Integration tests run inside a database transaction by default, which
>   is rolled back at the end of the each test. This means that data saved
>   during a test is not persisted to the database. Add a transactional
>   property to your test class to check transactional behaviour:
>
> ```
> class MyServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {
>     static transactional = false
>     void testMyTransactionalServiceMethod() {
>         …
>     }
> }
> ```

There fore this should answer your question

```
...
class CompanyServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

static transactional = false
...
```

.